# Handle DateTime in order to display only Date without Time with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a `DateTime Field` in order to select the soccer match day and I used this field in order to create part of my slug string.

I have:

```
public class Match
{

    [Required, Display(Name = "Date du match")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? MatchDay { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Mot-clé")]
    public string Slug
    {
        get { return "_" + MatchDay; }
    }
}
```

On my Index.cshtml page, my `MatchDay` field is well displayed for exemple with `25/07/2019`, but my slug value displayed is not good because I get `_25/07/2019 00:00:00`. 
I would like to get `_25/07/2019`

Do you have any idea to do that ?
I'm pretty new with `C#`/`ASP.NET` and I don't find anything about this issue.

Thank you

Comment: Didn't find .. I'm learning C#/ASP.NET since 1 week only, I'm from python environment ... I tried lot of things but without find the solution.. I tried to handle MatchDay field without to try handling Slug field

Comment: I don't have the choice, my job forces me to learn new environments .. But as I have some issues in my code and I don't know to solve each one, my searches are probably not optimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just print your date as you wish like this:

```
MatchDay.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

you can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you very much @BrunoBelmondo, it works fine !

Answer (score 1):

Using the current curture of the thread, the funcrion below with format and return only the date portion of the value.

```
MatchDay.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @RossBush, it works fine too !